# How to multiply user input by a decimal number in python?

Tags: python, math, input, floating-point, integer

Hello I am having trouble with using strings and integers during multiplication. If there is something I do not think I have done anything fundamentally wrong but then again, it's not working so I probably have done!

This is my code as of now.

```
    #This is where I ask the user for input for a value 
UI = print (float(input("Enter your value here: ")))
#Here I have numbers that I need to multiply the input by
FRT = (float(0.290949)
SRM = (float(0.281913)
#Here is the multiplication but this is where the issue occurrs
QV = (float("FRT"*"UI"))
SV = (float("SRM"*"UI"))
```

Both of these lines at the end have issues, I have tried using different set ups with using the numbers instead of defining them as FRT and SRM and using integer before float etc, but with these lines they both give the error "could not convert string to float "FRT""

Comment: Some of your parentheses are not closed.

Comment: you should do `QV = (float(FRT*UI))` instead of `QV = (float("FRT"*"UI"))`, cause `FRT` and `UI` are variables, but inside `" "` they are treated like strings .... Also you can't print and at the same time assign a value !!! Finally you have extra `(`

Comment: Hey, so I changed the end part and that issue is now a gone. With regards to the second part of the commment, does that mean that in the line 

        UI = print (float(input(".......:")))
I am trying to make the value inputted a float ? Does that mean afterwards, I should use the UI value and make it a float on a separate line? Sorry for these really bad questions, I am very new to this and english is not my native language so i cant formulate sentences very well

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues with your code

First of all, you have not closed your parenthesis on lines 4 and 5

Secondly, you're trying to call variables by strings. That isn't how it works

```
QV = (float("FRT"*"UI"))
```

should be

```
QV = (float(FRI * UI))
```

Lastly, `input` already displays text, so you don't need to `print` anything, and since `print` returns `None`, UI will always be `None`.

```
UI = print (float(input("Enter your value here: ")))
```

should be

```
UI = float(input("Enter your value here: "))
```

So, the complete debugged code should be:

```
#This is where I ask the user for input for a value 
UI = float(input("Enter your value here: "))
#Here I have numbers that I need to multiply the input by
FRT = (float(0.290949))
SRM = (float(0.281913))
#Here is the multiplication but this is where the issue occurrs
QV = (float(FRT*UI))
SV = (float(SRM*UI))
```

Comment: Also note that you're using unnecessary parenthesis, but that's a problem for another day

Comment: Hi, sorry when I put the original code into this comment I did not copy it properly. I didn't not have the brackets. Thank you for the help very quick and concise. I did not know that input prints by itself, and I did not know that " " treated values as strings. Thank you.

Comment: @Gramaru I'm glad I could help! If you don't mind, and you find it fitting to do so, please mark my answer as the accepted answer so anyone who finds this question can find the answer they need :)

Answer (score 0):

"FRT" is a string, made of the letters F, R & T. If you want to refer to the variable FRT, do not use quotation marks. `QV = (float("FRT"*"UI"))` is trying to first multiply the string "FRT" by the string "UI", and then convert the result to a float. Since string multiplication is not defined, you get an error.

In your current code, I am unsure of what UI is, since you did not make it equal to a number but to the result of a `print()`. Your first line should be replaced by

```
UI = float(input("Enter your value here: "))
print(UI)
```

Then, `QV = FRT * UI` will do what you want, since both FRT and UI are floats. The parentheses around each operation are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #This is where I ask the user for input for a value 
UI = print (float(input("Enter your value here: ")))
```

Above won't do what you want, print doesn't return anything

```
UI = float(input("..."))
print(UI)
```

If using python 2.7 us raw_input, not input

```
#Here I have numbers that I need to multiply the input by
FRT = (float(0.290949)
SRM = (float(0.281913)
```

You just need:

```
FRT = 0.290949
```

No need to convert a float into a float

```
#Here is the multiplication but this is where the issue occurrs
QV = (float("FRT"*"UI"))
SV = (float("SRM"*"UI"))
```

You are multiplying strings above, do this:

```
QV = FRT * UI
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want your output as ?

The error your making is that the two strings are variables, so remove the quotes off the variable so your code should look like this :

```
#This is where I ask the user for input for a value 
UI = print (float(input("Enter your value here: ")))
#Here I have numbers that I need to multiply the input by
FRT = (float(0.290949)
SRM = (float(0.281913)
#Remove the quotes from the variables below and you get this
QV = (float(FRT*UI))
SV = (float(SRM*UI))
```

Comment: Some problems here: `UI` is now `None` and there are too many and too many missing brackets. Please test your code before posting.